# Mentioning just constrained fields inside instance of typeclass

Tags: haskell, typeclass

Hello i want to know is there any way having a `type` that implements a `typeclass` to put a constraint on a field without decomposing all the type?(or simply put without enumerating all its other fields in the instance declaration? )

Example:

```
data A=A | BB | CCC deriving( Show)

class T a where
  mymethod::a->Bool

instance T A where
 mymethod a = length . show $ a >1

data Complex b = Complex{
                  a::Int,
                  b::A,
                  c::String
                  }

instance (T b) => T (Complex a b c)
```

Looking above in the last line, is there any way to enumerate just the fields that we want to put constraints on? (in our case `b` which implements `T` typeclass).

Can we put `wildcards` or any other thing to not put all fields?
**E.g**:
 `instance (T b) => T (Complex _ b _)`
or even better

```
 instance (T b) => T Complex {b ? }
```

Comment: but here there is only *one* type parameter for complex: an `a`. The number of parameters of the *data constructor* is three, but of the *type constructor* (`instance`s work on that meta-level), there is one parameter.

Comment: Furthermore this `a` has no use here, since you never specify a field with a type that is defined in terms of `a`.

Comment: I am not sure i am following.I made some edits in the meantime.

Comment: The field inside `Complex` that implements the `T` typeclass is `b`.

Comment: No, the `b` parameter has type `A` which is a real type, not `a`...

Comment: Oh you are right i modified.After edit is what i wanted .The `b` parameter to be type constrained.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174888/discussion-between-bercovici-adrian-and-willem-van-onsem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After fixing your implementation of `mymethod` for `A` (you need parentheses around the first argument to `>`), the following works for me:

```
data Complex = Complex{
                  a::Int,
                  b::A,
                  c::String
                  }

instance T Complex where
    mymethod c = mymethod (b c)
```

I have removed the type parameter to `Complex` -- I suspect you were getting confused and believing there was a connection between the type named `b` and the field named `b` when there wasn't. If you want, you could make that connection explicit (here I'll use different names to emphasize how the connection is made, but you could drop the `Ty`s and `Field`s below and still have valid code):

```
data Complex aTy bTy cTy = Complex
    { aField :: aTy
    , bField :: bTy
    , cField :: cTy
    }

instance T bTy => T (Complex aTy bTy cTy) where
    mymethod val = mymethod (bField val)
```

Comment: I think i got confused with the type constructor.I do not know : in the instance declaration you must place the `type` or `data` constructor?.If it is the `type`  then i wanted to know how do you manage something  like `Complex a b c`=`Complex{ a::T,b,c }` (b and c would implement another typeclass).

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian Instance heads mention a type constructor, possibly applied to some type variables. I will add a sentence or two about parameterized types.

Comment: Ok so in the case where you wish to only apply constraint on one parameter `bTy` for example.Is there any way to omit all other type parameters in the `instance ` decalaration? `instance T bTy =>(Complex x0,x1....xN     bTy      y1,y2...yN )` ....can i say something like `instance T bTy=>(Complex bTy _ ....)` .

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian No.

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive  answers.This is what i wanted to know,but i learned more thanks to you in the process :D